# I want to display the list of all children in a treeView in a new list

Tags: javascript

I have a treeView object. I want to create a new array where the children of each parent are listed.

I tried this

```
  if (s.submenu.length > 0) {
    s.submenu.map(c => {
      res = [...res, c]
    })
  }
})
```

```
input
[
 {label:"A",child:[{label:"B",child:[{label:"C"]child:[]}]}}]

Ouput

  [
  {lable: "A",child: [{label:"B"},{label:"C"} ]},
```

Comment: Can you create a minimal reproducible example? It's difficult to solve your problem without context.

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursion and destruct each child item to filter the child property out:

```js
const collect = (items, out = []) => {
  for(const {child, ...item} of items){
    out.push(item);
    child.length && collect(child, out);
  }
  return out;
};

const result = items.map(item => ({...item, child: collect(item.child)}));
$pre.textContent = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
```

```html
<script>

const items = [
    {
        label: "A",
        child: [{
            label: "B", child: [{ label: "C", child: [] }, { label: "H", child: [] }]
        }]
    },
    {
        label: "D",
        child: [{
            label: "E", child: [{ label: "F", child: [] }]
        }]
    }
];
</script>
<pre id="$pre"></pre>
```

Comment: @Recep can you add the second object to the question and fix the desired output?

Comment: @Recep i've added some data, works fine

Comment: @Recep you could also upvote (the arrow up)

Comment: @Recep if you accepted please do again, sometimes the accept checkbox is reset back